# How to get only expired subscrptions in Recurely using PHP?

Tags: recurly

I would like to create a report in my admin dashboard which give me all expired subscriptions list.

Comment: You should at least add *any* starting point, where an answer could start.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for sharing. Did you have a question?

Comment: @stephenking, Do we have any method in recurly which can give only expired subscription ?

Comment: No, I have no idea. I just noticed the "recurely" tag. I don't know that application. Thought your using a homegrown PHP software. Still your question lacks a question.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try

```
$subscriptions = Recurly_SubscriptionList::getActive();
foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
  print "Subscription: $subscription\n";
}
```

The state of subscriptions to return: "active", "canceled", "expired", "future", "in_trial", "live", or "past_due". A subscription may belong to more than one state.

you can filter as per your requirement.

[Source](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/list-subscriptions)